# Easy way to create / generate new Angular component in Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, angular-components, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

Working on ASP.NET core project (Angular) & Visual Studio as my IDE.

Is there an easy way to generate Angular component files and register the new component in the app module in Visual Studio?

Comment: Use Angular cli

Answer (score 15):

Just open the integrated terminal in VS Code and use the Angular CLI commands `ng generate` or its alias `ng g`. Here's the list of some options that you can use with the ng g command:

- `ng g c` -  generate a new component
- `ng g s` -  generate a new service
- `ng g d` -  generate a new directive
- `ng g m` -  generate a new module
- `ng g p` -  generate a new pipe

Each of these commands requires an argument(s), e.g. the name of the component to generate. For the complete list of available options and arguments run the command `ng help` generate or refer to the Angular CLI documentation. Here are some of the examples of using the `ng g` command:

- `ng g c product` will generate four files (.ts, .html, .css, .spec.ts) for a new product component in the directory src/app/product and will add the ProductComponent class to the declaration property of `@NgModule`
- `ng g c product -is -it -spec=false` will generate a single file product.component.ts with inlined styles and a template in the directory src/app/product and will add ProductComponent to the declarations property of `@NgModule`
- `ng g s product` will generate file product.service.ts containing a class decorated with `@Injectable()` and the file product.service.spec.ts in the directory src/app
- `ng g s product -m app.module` will generate the same files as the above command and will also add ProductService to the `providers` property of `@NgModule`

Comment: Navigating to component folder  and generating each time using 'ng g' commands will take more time. How about Visual studio IDE.

Comment: you don't need to navigate to the component folder. Open the integrated terminal and run ng g.

Comment: @YakovFain posted the whole cli documentation +1. great way to generate quick components

Comment: Rahul, I truly regret that I spent time answering your question. What do I get back? Accusations that I copy pasted CLI docs.  Good luck.

Comment: Not sure how this is marked as an answer since it provides instructions on how to do this from a different program... There isn't an integrated terminal inside visual studio, but it is being considered as you can see here: [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/516314/integrated-terminal-in-visual-studio-2019-similar.html). Options I would recommend are 1) Continue working inside Visual Studio and just generate components using command prompt, or 2) once your asp.net core with angular solution is created, use VS Code to program the Angular portion (Client App folder).

Comment: Downvoted as it relates to VS Code, question was regarding Visual Studio IDE

Comment: There appears to be a useful extension for VS Code too https://github.com/cyrilletuzi/vscode-angular-schematics

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer from the following article:
[Exploring Angular Fundamental With Visual Studio 2017](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/exploring-angular-fundamental-with-visual-studio-2017/)

(I did this in VS 2019)

- Download Angular Templates if you have not already: [Angular Templates Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xpasza.Angular4ItemTemplates)
- Right click on your app folder (or wherever you want to place the component): Add -> New Item.
- Search for Angular in the top right search field.
- Select Angular Component.